# Cannot access sdcard on Android 9 from Settings?

Tags: settings, storage

This is weird; I have an Android 9 device, and I have added an sdcard there. Using a standalone file manager, I can access the sdcard. However, when I go to Storage from Settings:

[image: Settings]

... I can see the entry for the sdcard as "Storag drove" (misspelled for some reason):

[image: Storage]

If I click/tap on Internal Shared Storage, I get an overview:

[image: Internal shared storage]

But, if I tap on "Storag drive", screen goes black, and then the Settings menu is shown again.

Tried to capture logcat, the only thing related seems to be this:

```
09-17 13:59:44.746  3638  6859 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/root/86C4-131A typ=vnd.android.document/root (has extras)} from uid 1000
09-17 13:59:44.748 11019 11019 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.settings, PID: 11019
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/root/86C4-131A typ=vnd.android.document/root (has extras) }
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2007)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageSettings.handlePublicVolumeClick(StorageSettings.java:334)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageSettings.onPreferenceTreeClick(StorageSettings.java:306)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1132)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1107)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.preference.Preference$1.onClick(Preference.java:172)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
09-17 13:59:44.750 11019 11019 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-17 13:59:44.754  3638  6859 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings$StorageDashboardActivity
09-17 13:59:44.761 11019 11019 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 11019 SIG: 9
```

What puzzles me, is that I would have guessed, SD card handling is something handled on the OS (Android) level - so I would not have expected the burden of handling this to be down to the vendor who modified Android for this device; but it does look like the vendor "forgot" to implement the overview for sdcard ?! ...

Does anyone know how come this problem happens on this device, and if it is possible to fix it (that is, get an overview for the sd card in Settings/Storage, instead of it crashing)? Could also a faulty SD card be a problem here (although, since my SD card is readable on the same device using a file manager, I guess it is not faulty)?